# How to get prices for multiple tickers for a given date with Quandl

Tags: c#, python, r, asp.net-web-api, quandl

I can already get the price for IBM on a given date :

https://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/GOOG/NYSE_IBM.json?trim_start=2012-11-01&trim_end=2012-11-01

Is there a way to query Quandl a single time and for multiple tickers ( all the same date)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 2 : I wrote to Quandl and as of  2015-04-07, the multiset querying feature is removed.** They are planning to reintroduce it in "*a couple of months*".

Update : The C# library is deprecated and the multi-set route it used is no longer valid :( I did not solve my problem yet

<strike>Well I found my answer on the libraries page of the Quandl website</strike>

http://quandl.com/help/libraries

The one that helped me is for C# : https://github.com/HubertJ/QuandlCS

and is providing the source code for how to construct a `multiset` query, which is what I needed, it seems.

Comment: Put the update at the bottom. works better that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Quandl` R package as follows

```
#get high prices(.2) from IBM, AAPL and TSLA for '2015-02-02'
mydata = Quandl(c("WIKI/IBM.2","WIKI/AAPL.2", "WIKI/TSLA.2"), start_date = "2015-02-02", end_date = "2015-02-02")
```

It results in:

```
   Date WIKI.IBM - High WIKI.AAPL - High WIKI.TSLA - High
1 2015-02-02          154.66           119.17         211.9499
```

Comment: thanks, would you happen to know what url it generates to request that data from the Quandl web API? I am in fact not working in R unfortunately...

Comment: There are Quandl libraries for several other languages... you might find one that better suits your needs here: https://www.quandl.com/help/libraries Let me know if it works, cheers!